# Hyperledger Fabric sample / first network error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm trying to up my first network from fabric sample.

When I'm running byfn.sh but getting this error:

> docker-compose: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1:
>   failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted
>   ERROR !!!! Unable to start network Error: No such container: cli

Answer (score 0):

- use the environment variable TMPDIR to point at a directory that has permission to execute files
  or
- remount /tmp with exec (sudo mount /tmp -o remount,exec) (it is not so good for security!)

https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1339